# SQLAlchemy relationship without stub class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm currently looking at a situation like the following -

```
user_association = Table('user_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', UUIDType, ForeignKey('user.id')),
    Column('personality_id', UUIDType, ForeignKey('personality.id'))
)

class User(Base, DBBase):
  __tablename__ = 'user'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
  name = Column(String), nullable = True)

  personalities = relationship(
        "Personality",
        secondary=user_association,
        back_populates="users"
    )

class Personality(Base, DBBase):
  __tablename__ = 'personality'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
  value = Column(String, nullable = True)

  users = relationship(
        "User",
        secondary=user_association,
        back_populates="personalities"
    )
```

The `Personality` object only has a value (and these values are hard-coded into the codebase, unlike typical objects).  I'm wondering if there's some way to achieve this same relationship behavior without an explicit stub table that encapsulates the personality.  Any ideas?

Comment: not clear with what do you want to achieve, replace `Personality` table with a python dict? how many records in this table?

Comment: @georgexsh Ideally, I want to connect the "user" to multiple personality strings while still retaining the built-in behavior of sqlalchemy (like appending new values with .append).

Comment: @p-freeman how many *unique* value of personalities then?

Comment: @georgexsh - about 10

Comment: hey any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Me too curious about how to define a non-table based "selectable" class in sqlalchemy and use it as a mapper, here is an alternative implementation, to put personality values into an enum column:

```
import enum  
from sqlalchemy_utils import ChoiceType

class PersonalityEnum(enum.IntEnum):
    I = 0
    N = 1
    T = 2
    J = 3

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    personalities = relationship(
        "UserPersonality",
        back_populates="users"
    )

class UserPersonality(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_personality'

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    personality = Column(ChoiceType(PersonalityEnum, impl=Integer()))
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('user_id', 'personality'),
    )

    users = relationship("User")

    def __init__(self, p):
        super().__init__(personality=p)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<UserPersonality user {self.user_id}, personality {self.personality.name}>'
```

you could use it like:

```
u = User(id=0, name='Guido van Rossum')
u.personalities.append(UserPersonality(PersonalityEnum.I))
u.personalities.append(UserPersonality(PersonalityEnum.J))
```